# How to center links in HTML

Tags: html, center, centering

I am really new to HTML and was wondering how you center multiple links with html?

I have been trying :

```
  <a href="http//www.google.com"><p style="text-align:center">Search</a>
```

But the problem is when I try to put other links behind it for example:

```
 <a href="http//www.google.com"><p style="text-align:center">Search</a><a href="Contact Us"><p style="text-align:center">Contact Us</a></p>
```

It just places them on separate lines. I believe this is happening because of the `<p>` function...but I only know HTML, I know you can do it in CSS but I was wondering if it can be done using just HTML.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

there are some mistakes in your code - the first: you havn't closed you `p`-tag:

```
<a href="http//www.google.com"><p style="text-align:center">Search</p></a>
```

next: `p` stands for 'paragraph' and is a block-element (so it's causing a line-break). what you wanted to use there is a `span`, wich is just an inline-element for formatting:

```
<a href="http//www.google.com"><span style="text-align:center">Search</span></a>
```

but if you just want to add a style to your link, why don't you set the style for that link directly:

```
<a href="http//www.google.com" style="text-align:center">Search</a>
```

in the end, this would at least be correct html, but still not exactly what you want, because `text-align:center` centers the text *in that element*, so you would have to set that for the element that *contains* this links (this piece of html isn't posted, so i can't correct you, but i hope you understand) - to show this, i'll use a simple `div`:

```
<div style="text-align:center">    
  <a href="http//www.google.com">Search</a>
  <!-- more links here -->
</div>
```

**EDIT:** some more additions to your question:

- `p` is not a 'function', but you're right, this is causing the problem (because it's a block-element)
- what you're trying to use *is* css - it's just inline instead of being placed in a seperate file, but you aren't doing 'just HTML' here

Comment: The end tag for p element **is** optional in HTML.

Comment: The guys below also covered your last point so collectively I learned a lot. Awesome reply! thanks.

Comment: @david: ok, thanks for the hint, i didn't knew that - but i hope you agree with me that having an end-tag is the more beautiful solution. (also, we don't know if he wanted to write xhtml - in this case, closing tags aren't optional)

Comment: I'd disagree with you on that, small is beautiful :) (It is subjective though). There are pros and cons to being explicit about optional end tags and to leaving them out.

Comment: @oezi: some things don't make sense in your reply though.  Adding text-align to an inline element is a bit weird, since text-align will align relative to the boundaries of the element, and an inline element will wrap around the size of its contents.  So there's no space left to shift the content around.

Comment: @Joeri: thats why i wrote "[...]because `text-align:center` centers the text in that element, so you would have to set that for the element that contains this links[...]" -  i just wanted to show up the mistakes step by step instead of just posting the correted html like otherones did without explaining whats the problem.

Comment: @oezi Ah, I see what you mean.  Looked a bit strange from here, but you're right :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a list of links, you should be marking them up as a list (and not as paragraphs).

Listamatic has [a bunch of examples of how you can style lists of links](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/), including a number that are vertical lists with each link being centred (which is what you appear to be after). It also has [a tutorial which explains the principles](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/index.htm).

That part of the styling essentially boils down to "Set `text-align: center` on an element that is displaying as a block which contains the link text" (that could be the anchor itself (if you make it display as a block) or the list item containing it.

Answer (score 3):

you would put them inside a `<p>` or a `<div>`

```
<p style="text-align:center">
    <a href="http//www.google.com">Search</a> 
    <a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
</p>
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/X8HM4/1/

Answer (score 2):

The <p> will show up on a new line.  Try wrapping all of your links in one single <p> tag:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><a href="http//www.google.com">Search</a><a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></p>
```

Comment: I tried this method, the problem with it is there is no spacing between search and contact us when I do this. :(

Comment: You'd need to add spacing.  I think oezi will cringe at this, but if nothing else, you can put a &nbsp; (non-breaking space) between each 'a' element.  You could also add a style="margin-right:4px;" to each 'a' element.  There are numerous ways.  But you have to implement at least one of 'em to make it happen :)

Comment: I'll cringe at it too. If the content isn't understandable when the styling is gone, then the markup is wrong.

Comment: Was just trying to illustrate that if you want to see a particular result, you need to make that happen.  But your point is well taken, and your answer below is the best of the bunch.  cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put them inside `<center>`, like this:

```
<center>
<a href="http//www.google.com">Search</a>
<a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
</center>
```

I've also created a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/9acgLf8e/

Answer (score 0):

`p` is not how you put text in `a`. That is the problem. The only solution is to put the text between `<a>` and `</a>`. For example:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64201994/edit" style="text-align:center;">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, one really easy way is to just do the old-fashioned way and save the hassle by using.
You can just change the margin-left or margin-right and the distance with the pixels in whichever way you prefer.

```
<a href:"#" style:"margin-left:"260px">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try doing a `nav` element with a `ul` element.  Mine has a `main` above but I don't think you need it.

```
<main>
<nav>
<ul><li><a href="http//www.google.com">search</a>
<li><a href="http//www.google.com">search</a>
<li><a href="http//www.google.com">search</a>
```

The code is something like this.
When ever I put in the code it wouldn't work right so you need to fill in the blank,
then center it.

```
main
nav
ul> li> a>: href="link of choice":name of link:/a>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @chris: I have formatted the code for you. In the future, please use a four-space prefix on each line of your code blocks (and backticks for inline code). See the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32975289/revisions) for details. I'm not sure what the last part of your answer is supposed to mean. I'm _guessing_ that it is meant to describe the incorrectly formatted code. If so, please [edit] your answer and remove the bits that are no longer needed.