# CSS link positioning not being centered

Tags: html, css

Ok well, pretty much I can align text to the center. I can use left and right margin auto and they will alright in the center and I put text positioning center and works, but I am trying to create a header with links and links are not moving like if I were to align a paragraph. I am pretty much trying to get my links to the center even horizontally.

```
div {
    border: black solid 5px;
    margin: 40px;
}

a {
    border: green solid 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: red;  
    text-align:right;
}

p{
    border: green solid 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: red;  
    text-align:center;
}
```

and this is my html

```
<link type="index/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <a href="sksksk">Link</a>
        <a href="sksksk">Link</a>
        <a href="sksksk">Link</a>


        <p> This is a paragraph and I can write whatever I like
            Yes this is a damn pargraph and I hate it and dont
            know what to say
        <p> This is a paragraph and I can write whatever I like
            Yes this is a damn pargraph and I hate it and dont
            know what to say
        <p> This is a paragraph and I can write whatever I like
            Yes this is a damn pargraph and I hate it and dont
            know what to say
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center links in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302386/how-to-center-links-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7sDRM/)

Wrap your links in a container and have that container have `text-align:center`

**html**

```
<div id="thisisadamncontainer">
    <a href="sksksk">Link</a>
    <a href="sksksk">Link</a>
    <a href="sksksk">Link</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#thisisadamncontainer
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center` to your `div`.

```
   div {
        border: black solid 5px;
        margin: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

`a` elements are `display: inline` by default which means they are treated as text by properties like `text-align: center`, so if you add that to their parent container `div` they will be centered.

Here is a **[working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uYc3/)**.

Comment: may i ask what is display: inline? I tried reading the description but i dont get it.

Comment: @user2997585 Please upvote and mark this answer as the solution (checkbox beneath vote) if my answer helped!  `display: inline` means the element is treated as a text element rather than a block element, which alters the way it behaves in the document, what CSS properties can be applied to it, and how it affects the elements around it in the DOM.  `em`, `strong`, `a`, and `span` are some common inline elements.

Comment: @user2997585 here are some resources that delve into the `display` property and what its assorted values mean: [one](http://learnlayout.com/display.html), [two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), [three](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Comment: @user2997585 you should also replace your `div` in both the HTML and CSS with a `ul`, because `li` elements are only supposed to be descendants of `ul` elements not `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The indusrty standard is to use an `ul` for your needs

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/29/

```
     <ul>
        <li><a href="sksksk">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="sksksk">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="sksksk">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```